# Is java.util.Observable in Android thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is java.util.Observable in Android thread-safe? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) says that only deleteObserver() and deleteObservers() are synchronized methods. What about addObserver(), set/clear/hasChanged()? Can I safely call addObserver() from different threads without locking around the Observable object?

Comment: how did "synchronized" come up in the javadoc? that is an implementation detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Android is based on Apache Harmony. I found the source code of the the Observable implementation of Harmony here : http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Apache-Harmony-Java-SE/java-package/java/util/Observable.java.htm.

It seems to me that the tried to make it thread-safe, but failed : they forgot to synchronize the countObservers method, as well as the set/has/clearChanged methods.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to look for the code but didn't know what implementation of Java Android uses.

Comment: Is the right solution to override these unsync'd methods in my derived Observable and declare them as synchronized? As in: `@Override public synchronized boolean hasChanged() { return super.hasChanged(); }`