# Is java.util.Observable thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, observer-pattern

In java's Observer pattern classes *Observer* and *Observable*, are calls made to Observable objects's *notifyObservers(Object arg0)*, in different threads, thread-safe?

Example:
I have multiple threads, all *Observables*, that will be calling *notifyObservers(...)* ever so often. All these threads report to a single *Observer* object.

Will I encounter concurrency issues, and what would be a better way to solve this?
I am aware of a possible solution using event listeners. However I am unsure how to implement it and also, I would like to stick with the Observer pattern implementation, if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123121/is-java-util-observable-in-android-thread-safe

Comment: Thanks I didnt see that, however it does not seem to answer this question, nor give any hint as to how to find out. This is for the normal Java implementation.

Comment: Try decompiling the Observable object in the java distribution that you are using.

Comment: @Angel ; I did in fact, and there is no mention of synchronization or thread-safety.

Comment: Well, if the methods are not "synchronized" which should show up in the java doc, it cant be really thread safe.

Comment: So the only way thread safety is implemented by Java is with synchronized method statements? I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the source code (I have Java 5 source, but it should be the same for Java 6 and 7) it seems like you only have synchronization on the `Observable` itself.

From the `notifyObservers(...)` method (in `Observable`):

```
synchronized (this) {
  //the observers are notified in this block, with no additional synchronization
}
```

Thus if the `Observer` doesn't change any shared data it should be fine. If it does - you could have multiple calls to `update(Observable, Object)` with different `Observable`s - you'd need to add synchronization on that shared data yourself.